# Send updated version of my Enterprise App? How?

Tags: iphone, enterprise

I have built an enterprise app and now i have an update coming up for this app. Now, how do i make my clients install this app? I read it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) but just want to make sure that it works and want to know if i have to take any precautions or anything which i need to do before i send the updated app to my clients?

**Anyone who has done this or who has an idea about this, please help me out!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if someone updates application then their document folder will remain as it is. so make sure that those existing data is not affecting your new version and if you want to retain some old data then keep same bundle identifier and ask user not to delete application.

Best way to test this is make a local server setup, then install old version, then update it with new version and test it again.

setup of local web server will not take more than 20 min.....

Hope this is helpful....